# Alter table with new column name every time in SQL table from Java

Tags: java, sql

I want to add column based on data means if am getting 5 value in warehouse then add 5 column in table like warehouse1, warehouse2, ..........etc.

```
//connection is defined here
Connection con = DbUtil.getConnection();
PreparedStatement stm = null;
ResultSet rs = null;    

int i = 1;
// in workaddress am getting unlimited value , i want to add column till condition got false
if(request.getParameter("workaddress") != null)        
{         
     // here i have define column name warehouse + i with increment but i got error duplicate column name                   
     stm = con.prepareStatement("ALTER TABLE tbl_buyer ADD warehouse" + i++ + " VARCHAR(100)");                        
     stm.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Seems like a horrible idea. Add rows for warehouses, not columns!

Comment: i have a table with 7 column

Comment: and i want to add multiple warehouse in warehouse column

Comment: dear jarlh please help me

Comment: Add one column, `warehouseid`!

Comment: I agree on the horrible idea part. Why do you think you need columns `warehouse1`, `warehouse2`, `warehouse3` etc.? Are you familiar with database design? Normal forms?

Comment: yes , you r right am not familiar with database design.

Comment: i have done using your method

Comment: thanks for the helping jarlh

Answer (score 0):

Try to add i++ before ( or use ++i ) because it affect the value then it makes the  increment , due to this it'll throw duplicate column name error .

```
i++;
stm = con.prepareStatement("ALTER TABLE tbl_buyer ADD warehouse" + i + " VARCHAR(100)");
```